# Invalid or unsupported command "update project -t -p" error building OpenH264

Tags: android, openh264

I am trying to compile [OpenH264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) as static libraries for *Android arm*. I executed following commands in `OpenH264`'s parent folder.

```
export PATH=/Full/Path/to/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
make OS=android NDKROOT=/Full/Path/to/ndk/android-ndk-r10e TARGET=21 ARCH=arm
```

I get the following **error message** at the end of the build.

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Full/Path/to/OpenH264/android/openh264/codec/build/android/dec'
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "update project -t 21 -p ."

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
make: *** [decdemo] Error 2
```

However, I am getting the following libraries as output which is waht I need,

```
libcommon.a
libdecoder.a
libencoder.a
libopenh264.a
libprocessing.a
```

The out put looks same as I got for building OpenH264 for iOS. **Seems** like the build is successful but not sure why the android related error ?

**Question:**
Is the build ok?
What can I do to get rid of the android related error?

Comment: Fairly certain your Android SDK is too new to use that command.

Answer (score 1):

this error caused by using a higher SDK tool to build encoder & decoder demo program. The "android" tool does not support "update project" in the higher SDK version. Actually, the openh264 libraries have been built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
make OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/vaiden/dev/tools/android-ndk-r17c TARGET=android-28 ARCH=arm64 NDKLEVEL=28 NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang
```

Seems to [do the trick](https://github.com/HippotecLTD/openh264-lib-android-64-bit).